# R : Map a column to column using key-value list

Tags: r, list

In R, I want to use a key-value list to convert a column of keys to values. It's similar to: [How to map a column through a dictionary in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28751879/1290264), but I want to use a list not a data.frame.

I've tried to do this using list and columns:

```
d = list('a'=1, 'b'=2, 'c'=3)
d[c('a', 'a', 'c', 'b')]  # I want this to return c(1,1,3,2) but it doesn't
```

However, the above returns a list:

```
list('a'=1, 'a'=1, 'c'=3, 'b'=2)
```

Comment: Try `unlist`  `unlist(d[c('a', 'a', 'c', 'b')], use.names=FALSE)` which gets a vector as you showed.

Comment: Make it an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unlist` is a useful function in this situation

```
unlist(d[c('a', 'a', 'c', 'b')], use.names=FALSE)
#[1] 1 1 3 2
```

Or another option is `stack` which returns the 'key/value' as columns in a 'data.frame'.  By subsetting the values column, we get

```
stack( d[c('a', 'a', 'c', 'b')])[,1]
#[1] 1 1 3 2
```